# Avoid 'Cannot read property of undefined' error when mapping data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I'm receiving some data back from Google Books API calls and I'm mapping the data into a lighter array I can then work with. I'm using this line to map the data I'm interested into:

```
data.items.map(function(book) {
  return { googleId : book.id, image : book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail, authors : reduceAuthors(book.volumeInfo.authors), title : book.volumeInfo.title, subtitle : book.volumeInfo.subtitle, publishedDate : book.volumeInfo.publishedDate, publisher : book.volumeInfo.publisher}
});
```

Most of the times it works just fine, but some times one of the elements is missing, may it be `imagelinks` or `authors` therefore I get this error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined"`.

What is the best way to avoid this error?

The only solution I have in mind is to first run a sanity check on the whole data and apply the map only after, but there maybe is a better solution? And wrapping everything in a try and catch throws me out of the mapping operation too early and doesn't complete with the rest of the data.

Comment: Checking your incoming data first is definitely the best solution. It'll alllow you to be very decisive on how missing data is handled, and provides a more robust error handling approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it inside `map()` function, without handle previously the entire data. With a ternary conditional , something like this:

```
 image : ((book.volumeInfo.imageLinks) ? book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail : undefined)
```

So if `book.volumeInfo.imageLinks` is null/empty/undefined there aren't error and the value inserted will be `undefined`, otherwise catch the thumbnail value.

Comment: But OP would have to check each property, and then assign the key if it is there, like `if (book.volumeInfo && book.volumeInfo.imageLinks && book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail) output.image = book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail`. Not ideal... I'd recommend using something like lodash `_.get` and `_.set`

Comment: Generally speaking it might be not ideal but it works perfectly in my case. I get error whenever I try to access a nested property with an undefined parent, and I do so only with the image and the author so I just need to check two times, not once for each property.